# Decision tree feature importances on a test set

Tags: cross-validation, feature-selection, cart, importance

Many tree based models come with a built in feature importance method usually based on impurity decrease (ex. sklearn RandomForest). Would it be possible to calculate feature importances on a test set (out-of-sample data), in other words the per-feature contribution to impurity decrease with respect to an external dataset? If so does anyone know of any implementations? It seems fairly straightforward and more robust than the usual approach, I just haven't seen this done before.

Comment: That means you would have to fit the model on the test set.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to measure impurity decrease on the test set using the splits learned on the train set?

Comment: Does Random Forest output any statistics such as correlations, or covariances?  If so you might be able to compare these to the same statistics on the test data set and maybe do a hypothesis test